# Re-weight the input to a neural network

Tags: pytorch

For example, I feed a set of images into a CNN. And the default weight of these images is 1. How can I re-weight some of these images so that they have different weights? Can 'DataLoader' achieve this goal in pytorch?

I learned two other possibilities:

- Defining a custom loss function, providing weights for each sample as I require.
- Repeating samples in the training set, which will result in more frequent samples having a higher weight in the final loss.

Is there any other way, we can achieve that? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways to achieve this.

1. Pass on the weight explicitly, when you backpropagate the gradients.

   After you computed loss, and when you're about to backpropagate, you can pass a `Tensor` to `backward()` and all the subsequent gradients will be scaled by the corresponding element, i.e. do something like

   ```
   loss = torch.pow(out-target,2)
   loss.backward(my_weights) # is a Tensor of same dimension as loss
   ```

However, if you use want to assign individual weights in a batch, you can't use the custom loss functions from the `nn.module` which aggregates the loss over all samples in a batch.

2. Use `torch.utils.data.sampler.WeightedRandomSampler`

   If you use PyTorch's `data.utils` anyway, this is simpler than multiplying your training set. However it doesn't assign exact weights, since it's stochastic. But if you're iterating over your training set a sufficient number of times, it's probably close enough.